# Keep the animation running

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

When the mouse is over a span .test it slideToggle a div .frame. Inside .frame I have some div .test2, when I click on .test2 it changes the html of .test but it also stops the main animation. How can I keep the animation?
My code is:

```
$('.test').hover(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var elWidth = el.width();
    $(el).append('<div class="frame"></div>');
    var frame = $('.frame:last');
    var posTop = el.offset().top;
    var posLeft = el.offset().left;
    frame.hide().css({
        'left': posLeft,
        'top': posTop,
        'width':200
    });
    frame.html('<div class="test2">test2</div><div class="test2">test2</div><div class="test2">test2</div>').slideToggle(150);
},function() {
    var frame = $('.frame:last');
    frame.stop().slideToggle(150, function() {
        frame.remove();
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.test2', function() {
    $('.test').html('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb');
});
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/2PPwD/

if you go to the jsfiddle you'll see that if you click on "test2" it will cloes the div .frame, how can I let .frame open?

Comment: Do be careful about a selector like `.frame:last` which has no context. If I were you I would do `var frame = $('<div class="frame"></div>');` then `$(el).append(frame)`. In your second function I would use `var frame = $('.frame',this)` which will find the element matching `.frame` within the context of `.test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for your `onclick` event instead. @Javalsu is right about the problem. This is the solution.

```
$(document).on('click', '.test2', function() {
    $('.test').contents()[0].data='bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vCDSP/1/

Comment: Updated the fiddle link, it needed the rev 1

Answer (score 1):

Why are you nesting the frame inside of the span?

What's happening is on hover, you're creating the frame, then animating it.

Then on click, you are destroying the frame.

If you're lucky and the mouse is still over the initial span, then it triggers the hover event again and redraws the frame and animates it again.

You need to place the frame outside of the span so you don't keep destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing everything in `.test`, the frame too. You can utilize the `detach()` method, which removes an element but stores it in a variable for later use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.test2', function() {
    var frame = $('.frame:last').detach();
    $('.test').html('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb').append(frame); 
});
```

Note that `toggle()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 (Your fiddle shows you using 2.0). You could use `mouseenter().mouseleave()` instead.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PPwD/2/)